# SQL like conditions

Tags: sql

What does this mean within my like statement?

```
LIKE '%[ .,!?]' + keyword + '[ .,!?]%'
```

I'm trying to get something, that will match for whole words

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LIKE '%[ .,!?]' + keyword + '[ .,!?]%'
```

means

find anything that meets these conditions:

- Is preceded by a space, comma, exclamation, question mark
- Matches the keyword
- Is followed by a space, comma, exclamation, question mark

Comment: also, don't forget that the % will match any chars on the start and end

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that this will lead to a full table/index scan, if your table is large you may need to rethink.